# Firebase dynamic links with React-Native not working in testflight build

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

I have a react-native app where I am integrating firebase-dynamic links.
I am generating a link with firebase API with below payload:

```
{
"dynamicLinkInfo":{
"domainUriPrefix":"https://{app_name}.page.link",
"link":"https://{domain}.com?id=12344",
"androidInfo":{
  "androidPackageName”:”android:package”
},
"iosInfo":{
  "iosBundleId": “iOS:bundleID”,
  "iosAppStoreId": “app_store_id"
  }   
 }
}
```

I am retrieving the deep link using the below code in my `App.js`:

```
dynamicLinks()
.getInitialLink()
.then((link) => {
 if (link != null) {
 console.log("DYNAMIC_LINK", link.url)
 }
```

This is working fine when I run the build locally i.e. when I run it from my machine. I am able to retrieve the deep link data but, when I pushed the same build on test flight; it is not working.
On the test flight build, I am not able to get the deep link data.

Any help is appreciated.